# How to stop all methods in promise chain from being called after an error

Tags: bluebird

```
promise
      .catch(e => { console.log('Error'); return; })
      .finally(e => { console.log('Hi Mum'); return; })
      .then(e => { console.log('hello'); return; });
```

When the promise is rejected, the `then` method is still called.

How do I stop the `then` method from being called after a rejection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `then` *to late** you should've called it before catch:

```
promise
  .then(e => { console.log('hello'); return; });
  .catch(e => { console.log('Error'); return; })
  .finally(e => { console.log('Hi Mum'); return; })
```

Promises form a chain and it is perfectly valid to continue after catching something.

*: By too late I mean the `then` handler registers as continuation to the Promise returned from `finally`, not the initial Promise.